# Issue While Passing Dynamic Datas in React Chart Js 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have successfully passed dynamic datas to React Chart JS 2 but i am having problem displaying it.
Please find the attached screenshot of the chart.

[image: Line Chart]
I am trying to make a line chart for all the expenses vs month. As you can see there are two arrays that is visible in the console of the screenshot. One is of Amount spent and corresponding month it was spent can be seen in the array below it. Eg: 529 was spent on May and 100 was spent on April.

Here is my Chart.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import moment from 'moment';


const Chart = (props) => {
  console.log(props.expenses);
  const amount = props.expenses.map((expense) => {
    // console.log(expense.amount);
    // console.log(moment(expense.createdAt).format('MMMM'));
    return expense.amount;
  });
console.log(amount);

  const createdAt = props.expenses.map((expense) => {
    const arr_createdAt = expense.createdAt;
    return moment(arr_createdAt).format('MMMM');
  });
console.log(createdAt);

  const data = {
  labels: **createdAt**,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'My First dataset',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,0.4)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: **amount**
    }
  ]
};

return (
  <div>
    <div className = "page-header">
        <div className = "content-container">
            <h1 className = "page-header__title">CHART</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className = "content-container">
          <h2>Line Example</h2>
          <Line data={data} />
      </div>
  </div>
)};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    expenses : state.expenses
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Chart);
```

What i want to do is bucket all the expenses that was spent on May and dispaly total expense sum in May Line and do same for other months as well.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: i'd make that a class

Comment: @JoeWarner: Can you please explain me more about this.

Comment: Its better to set data in react state, that way it will update the Chart automatically when the data is changed https://thecodeframework.com/how-to-use-chart-js-with-react-typescript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
`let reducedValue = props.expenses.reduce((acc, item) => {
    let index = acc.findIndex(accItem => moment(accItem.createdAt).format('MMM') === moment(item.createdAt).format('MMM'));
    if(index < 0){
        acc.push({...item});
    } else {
        acc[index].amount += item.amount;
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
let amount = reducedValue.map(item => item.amount);
let createdAt = reducedValue.map(item => moment(item.createdAt).format('MMM'));
`
```

Comment: Explaining why this solution works would be helpful for potential other users to be able to understand it.